# Aggregation of filtered related objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to count objects that match a criterion and group by a characteristic of a related object. For instance, if I have a set of models like this:

```
class Office(User):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Staff(User):
    home_office = models.ForeignKey(Office)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    appt_start = models.DateTimeField()
    appt_end = models.DateTimeField()
    client = models.ForeignKey(User)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And I wanted to get the number of appointments that resulted in "success" for each office, I could do a single raw SQL query like this:

```
SELECT office.name, COUNT(appointment.id)
    FROM appointment
        JOIN staff ON staff.id = appointment.provider_id
        JOIN office ON office.id = staff.home_office_id
    WHERE appointment.result = 'success' GROUP BY office.name;
```

I'd prefer to get this result using the ORM and Django's QuerySet aggregation & annotation functions if possible but after reading the docs and I don't think it's possible to aggregate based on fields of a related object but I wanted to ask in case I'd missed something.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Office.objects.filter(
    staff__appointment__result='success'
).values('name').annotate(appointments=models.Count('staff__appointment'))
```